# Toggle jQuery controls when clicking another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to put together a Leaflet based map for our college. We have just about everything done, but I'm running into a problem with the jQuery controls. We are using this block of code to highlight the jQuery buttons and send commands to Leaflet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
         $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
            } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
            }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.img-swap {cursor: pointer;}
</style>


<p align="center"><img src="images/item1_off.png" class="img-swap" width="94" height="93" alt="Locate Item 1" /></p>
<p align="center"><img src="images/item2_off.png" class="img-swap" width="106" height="76" alt="Locate Item 2" /></p>
```

This code works just fine when you click on the objects. The issue we have is that we need to fire an event to deselect an object (and undo the corresponding Leaflet events) when a new object is clicked.

For example, if we have five items, and you click item one, it turns red and the map highlights some buildings. When you click item two, it should turn red, turn item one back to normal, and un-highlight the buildings that one highlighted.

I can't find a way to make this happen. It only works for items that are clicked, not the other items. Is there a modification to this code that does that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var selected = null;

    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if (selected) {
            selected.src.replace("_on","_off");
            $(selected).removeClass("on");
        }
        this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        $(this).addClass("on");
        selected = this;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I would defined my on and off states in css then just change the class name on click.

```
<style> 
.onImage
{

height: 20px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-image: url("images/item1_on.png") 
     /* path relative to where the css is if not in page. */
}
 .offImage
{

height: 20px; /* set the match the size of the icon */
background-repeat: no repeat;
background-image: url("images/item1_off.png") 
     /* path relative to where the css is if not in page. */
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
    $(".switch").on('click', function(evtObj) {
        $(".onImage").removeClass("onImage").addClass("offImage");
        $(evtObj.target).removeClass("offImage").addClass("onImage");

      });
   });
</script>
<div class='switch offIcon'></div>
<div class='switch offIcon'></div>
```